# Get data from Powerpoint Chart to Excel Worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

**So when you right click a chart in Powerpoint and click Edit Data. A workbook will open up. I just want those data to be copied to my Excel file. Help me to extract every chart in each slide of powerpoint. Please help me Here's my code in PPT VBA so far:**

Sub PowerpointToExcel()

```
Dim PPTPres As Presentation
Dim PPTSlide As Slide
Dim PPTShape As Shape
Dim PPTTable As Table
Dim PPTChart As Chart
Dim PPTPlaceHolder As PlaceholderFormat

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

Dim PPTChartData As MSForms.DataObject

Set PPTPres = Application.ActivePresentation

On Error Resume Next

Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set PPTChartData = New MSForms.DataObject

For Each PPTSlide In PPTPres.Slides

    For Each PPTShape In PPTSlide.Shapes
    
        If PPTShape.HasChart Then
        
            Set PPTChart = PPTShape.Chart
            
        
            Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("A10000").End(xlUp)
            
            If xlRange.Value <> "" Then
                
                Set xlRange = xlRange.Offset(1, 0)
                
            End If
            
            With PPTPres.Slides(PPTSlide).Shapes(PPTShape).Chart.ChartData
            .Activate
            .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:E10").Copy
            
            PPTChartData.GetFromClipboard
            
            End With
            
            SData = PPTChartData.GetText(1)
            xlRange.Value = SData
            xlRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = PPTSlide.Name
            xlRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = PPTChart.ChartData
            
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
Next




End Sub
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your existing code? Any error messages? If so, on which line?

Comment: No error but on the lines below. The data from Chart isn't copying, instead it just paste whatever the text I have copied last.

With PPTPres.Slides(PPTSlide).Shapes(PPTShape).Chart.ChartData
            .Activate
            .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:E10").Copy
            
            PPTChartData.GetFromClipboard
            
            End With